# Do all states in a DFA must be connected?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Could I construct (for some wired reason) a DFA that has a state that is not connected to anything, and it would still be legal?

I'm studying for a test, and I found a question that asks if an infinite DFA could represent a regular language, and I want to use a regular DFA and add all the infinite states not connected to the original. Can I do that?

Comment: Sure, states don't need to be reachable. Of course, you could accomplish the same thing by (a) having no accepting states (the empty language is regular) or (b) replacing a dead state with a dead "trail" that goes on forever or (c) defining the DFA to be an infinite $|\Sigma|$-ary tree where a node is accepting if it's in your target languages. With infinitely many states, it's pretty easy to accept anything you want.

Comment: Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: Still, it seems a bit contradictory to disconnect a state for a wired reason.

Comment: You have a formal definition. Read it, understand it and answer the question yourself. That said, the notion "infinite deterministic finite automaton" does not make a lot of sense. Also, you *can* have infinitely many states, all reachable, and the described language is still regular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As babou mentions, infinite deterministic automata are rather powerful. In fact, they can compute *all* languages. Consider the "universal deterministic automaton" which is a $|\Sigma|$-ary infinite tree, with one state per each string in $\Sigma^*$. By choosing the set of accepting states to be $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$, we obtain an automaton which accepts $L$.

Regarding connectedness, while a DFA need not be connected, every disconnected DFA is equivalent to a smaller one which is connected; the minimal DFA is always connected.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect a trick question in the material you are studying - there are no DFAs with an infinite number of states in the first place.

in fact, the whole point of D/NFAs is their finiteness. if you could have an inifinite number of (reachable) states in your NFA you'd actually be able to recognize any language; just take for every word in your language the trivial deterministic recognizer and connect a global start state with $\lambda$-transitions to the start state of each of these automata.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly add as many disconnected states as you
want. However, I think that the definition of DFA or NFA stipulates
that the number of states is finite (that is what the **F** stands
for). So it would not be a DFA.  However, even with an infinity of
states, it can certainly recognize a regular language, if
appropriately built (as you suggest, for example).

The reason why the definition stipulates a finite number of states is
that an infinite number of states will allow you to recognize about
anything.  After all, a Turing Machine is an automaton just like the
DFA, but with an infinite number of states, that you can actually
enumerate, as you can enumerate the transitions (also infinite in
number).

I have not looked at it previously, but I believe that you can
actually do much better than Turing Machine with a DIA (Deterministic
Infinite Automaton). You have only countably many TM, but you have
continuously many DIAs, as many as you have real numbers. So I should
expect that they would do things one does not even expect from TM.

On the other hand, anything they do, they will do in finite number of
steps, so that remains a limitation (as compared to Zeno machines, or machines using looping time-lines). I
did not see anything in a fast look on the [hypercomputation page of wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation).

I am sure someone has worked on continuous machines (I do not dare
call them *real* machines, *real numbers* are enough of an abusive claim). Maybe looking at work on computable reals,
and related literature can put some light on this.

They can solve the halting problem for ordinary TM. You just follow
the usual diagonalization construction that describe a solution for
the halting problem. Since you do not require that construction to be
describable by an ordinary Turing Machine, there is no
contradiction. Isn't this a happy world?

The only difficulty, albeit a minor one, is that we do not know how to
implement them. Miracles are not of this world.. . yet.

Comment: A small point: I wouldn't call the class of automata with infinitely many states "continuous" since continuity is a quite different property, related to the behaviour of functions. Each individual automaton would be countable; there would just be uncountably many of them.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks. I agree. Actually I called them DIA, or NIA while I am at it. I meant to say Continuum rather than Continuous. It happens to be the same word in my native language. I was referring to cardinality. I will change that in the next edit.